# Per "post", icons more further left

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

So basically I have a small project I'm working on. Here's the issue. For every post the icons move further away from the right and go towards the left. I've tried `float: right` and `margin-right: 10px`, but never seem to more to the right. So here's a picture of what I see.

[image]

As you can see the heart and comment icons make an almost stair like effect. Here's the code I'm using.

My markup:

```
<div class="header"></div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="post">
            <div class="icons">
            <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-comment"></i>
            </div>
            <h1 class="message">@alex likes cats</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="post">
            <div class="icons">
            <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-comment"></i>
            </div>
            <h1 class="message">@alex likes cats</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="post">
            <div class="icons">
            <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-comment"></i>
            </div>
            <h1 class="message">@alex likes cats</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And my CSS

```
.message{
    font-family: 'Avenir Next';
    font-weight: 400;
    padding-left: 35px;
    line-height: 70px;
}

.post{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.fa-heart{  
    transition: 0.5s;
    line-height: 155px;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 24px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.fa-heart:hover{
    transition: 0.5s;   
    line-height: 155px;
    color: #FF6699;
    font-size: 24px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.fa-comment{    
    transition: 0.5s;
    line-height: 155px;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 24px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.fa-comment:hover{
    transition: 0.5s;   
    line-height: 155px;
    color: #FF6699;
    font-size: 24px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.icons{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

Plus [here's](http://jsbin.com/wogonefi/1) a demo. I'm not really sure what's wrong. So any help would be great.

Comment: You use `float: right` and these things are so big that they occupy the next row. So each one stack to the left of the previous one. [Reducing the size of these icons will help.](http://jsbin.com/wogonefi/3/edit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove line-height and float:right for .fa-heart, .fa-comment and their hover counterparts.
http://jsbin.com/wogonefi/6

Another option:

```
.post{
    width: 100%;
    height: 155px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

The height has been modified as to accomodate the line-height of the icons.

Comment: Well I kind of need the line height so that then I can align them with another element....

Comment: Then post another question with this problem

Comment: Added another solution.